# Using a method from one test in another

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

This seems simple, but for some reason I've not got it to work.

I'm using Selenium with Nunit.

I have one class called 'Registration_Test' in which I have a method named 'completeRegistrationForm()' which does as described.

I would like this method to be available for me to call in a number of different tests.

This is what I have in my second test.

```
Registration_Test reg = new Registration_Test();
reg.completeRegistrationForm();
```

This compiles happily but when I run it in Nunit I get the following:

```
SeleniumTests.Check_Links.Check_linksTest:
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and it indicates that reg.completeRegistrationForm(); line is the culprit.

Appreciate any help you can offer.

Here are my two tests:

Registration-test.cs

```
namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class Registration_Test
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://custom-creative-404-dropbox:8080/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            Console.Write("Unable to Stop Selenium and/or close the browser");
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Registration()
    {

        completeRegistrationForm();

        //back to home page.
        selenium.Click("link=Home");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }


    public void completeRegistrationForm()
    {
        selenium.Open("/");
        selenium.Click("link=Register");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");

        string uniqueVal = selenium.GetEval("\"AutomatedTest\" + (new Date().getDate()) + (new Date().getTime())");
        //use moment instead.

        selenium.Type("id=RegistrationForm_TxtName", uniqueVal);

        selenium.Type("id=RegistrationForm_TxtUserName", uniqueVal + "@creative-404.com");
        selenium.Type("id=RegistrationForm_TxtPassword", uniqueVal);
        selenium.Type("id=RegistrationForm_TxtRePassword", uniqueVal);
        selenium.Click("id=RegistrationForm_Button1");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");

        for (int second = 0; ; second++)
        {
            if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
            try
            {
                if (selenium.IsTextPresent("Registration was successful!")) break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.Write("Unable to find the Registration successful message. Something has gone wrong..");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
}
```

and Test-Links.cs (this test was made really just to test this out)

```
namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class Check_Links
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://custom-creative-404-dropbox:8080/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Check_linksTest()
    {
        Registration_Test reg = new Registration_Test();
        reg.completeRegistrationForm();

        selenium.Open("/home.aspx");
        selenium.Click("link=Home");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("link=Gallery");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you please show the code for completeRegistrationForm()

Comment: @HatSoft sure, I've updated my post with the code. Thanks!

Comment: The code in method looks alright can you please copy/paste the stack trace showing InnerException

Comment: @HatSoft I'm not sure I know how to show the inner exception in Nunit? I'm running the tests from in there not Visual Studio. I have this one only.    

System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at SeleniumTests.Registration_Test.completeRegistrationForm() in F:\Programs\Dropbox\Dropbox\Custom-Creative-404\Selenium\Creative-404-Tests\Creative-404\Registration-Test.cs:line 54
   at SeleniumTests.Check_Links.Check_linksTest() in F:\Programs\Dropbox\Dropbox\Custom-Creative-404\Selenium\Creative-404-Tests\Creative-404\Test-Links.cs:line 42

Comment: What is on line 54 of `RegistrationTest.cs`?  When you create a `Registration_Test` object, where does it get its `selenium` from?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I think you might be on to something here. I've added my entire 2 tests above so that you can see what's going on :)

Comment: I think @LukeWoodward has figured it out. You need to call the `SetupTest` method before calling `completeRegistrationForm`

Comment: @MikeTwo ah, that's exactly it! I've been spun around because they're called the same thing as I've just used selenium default generated code in the main. Scope was my enemy. Thanks very much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach to the nUnit process to debug the failing line http://frater.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/debugging-nunit-tests-under-visual-studio-2010/.

You can configure visual studio to break on exceptions in Debug>Exceptions. Next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" select "User-unhandled".

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful :)

Comment: it gives me the same information however this will be great when I want to step through and see where things go. Thanks very much. I guess my issue is that Test-links doesn't know anything about 'selenium'. Now I need to figure out why... haha